# reverse() doesn't resolve in django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

django-rest-framework question:  TLDR: reverse() doesn't work when everything I'm being told says it should.

OK, Longer version:   I have a route that works when I navigate to it.  "/api/tag/"  I have the route set where all my api routes are set

```
router.register("tag", TagViewSet, basename="tag")
```

TagViewSet is based off a ModelViewSet.

If I comment this line out /api/tag/ doesn't work in the browser (so it's the authoritative place).  The questions comes when I replace "/api/tag/" in my tests to `reverse('tag-list')` or `reverse('tag:tag-list')`.  Neither resolves.   When I put in (using debug mode) http://localhost:port/api/sldkfjalsdjfalskdjflaksj I get a list of things that resolve which has the line

```
api/ ^tag/$ [name='tag-list']
```

So I'm wondering what else I can check for to make this reverse() or reverse_lazy() to work.

*EDIT because of comment*
******this is config/urls.py *********
...

```
urlpatterns += [
    # API base url
    path("api/", include("config.api_router")),
```

******this is config/api_router.py********

```
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter, SimpleRouter

from athenaeum_tdd_coreapi.users.api.views import UserViewSet
from tag.views import TagViewSet


if settings.DEBUG:
    router = DefaultRouter()
else:
    router = SimpleRouter()

router.register("tag", TagViewSet, basename="tag")


app_name = "api"
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the urls file? Have you defined `app_name` in the file or passed `namespace=` when including you urls in the parent/root?

Comment: `app_name` in the urls file is used as the namespace, you probably want `reverse('api:tag-list')`

Comment: @IainShelvington You should get credit for the answer.   That was it.